# How to disable updates in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

Do I have a chance to disable unwanted updates in jenkins such as plugins, so the pipeline should not break while in pipeline. And it can break the stability of pipeline.

I looked at Configure System in Jenkins but I could not see any information about it.

Comment: What do you mean with *unwanted updates*? Jenkins updates or code updates?

Comment: I mean Jenkins update

Answer (score 9):

There is an option under Manage Jenkins: Configure System -> Administrative monitors configuration. Uncheck "Jenkins Update Notification".

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/jenkinsci-users/TSY2MhkTNJ4/FGuNd_BaBgAJ

Comment: That looks like just the message.

Answer (score 7):

Starting jenkins 2.230 you can add next JCasC yaml config:

```
jenkins:
  disabledAdministrativeMonitors:
    - hudson.model.UpdateCenter$CoreUpdateMonitor
```

More info:

https://github.com/jenkinsci/configuration-as-code-plugin

https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-56937

https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins/pull/4552

https://javadoc.jenkins.io/hudson/model/UpdateCenter.CoreUpdateMonitor.html

Answer (score 1):

Even if this was asked 4 years ago, I didn't find an answer on the internet even today. Thus, I had to find a solution myself. But I died inside a bit when I understood how to get rid of updates in my **Jenkins 2.289.1**.

So! To disable autoupdate of plugins, you need to go to *Manage Jenkins* -> *Manage Plugins* -> *Advanced* -> scroll down to the *Update Site* section, remove the default value from the *URL* box, and save changes (i.e. hit Enter or click the *Submit* button).

https://updates.jenkins-ci.org/current/update-center.json is points to the Jenkins update center. And the update center is used by Jenkins to download and install plugins, and it is updated regularly with new plugin releases. So, it knows where to find updates and casually installs it in matters of security. As far as I understood, in newer versions, you have to edit .YAMLs or exploit other artful tricks.
[image: How the box is look like in the tab]