# How can I setup groovy script to dismiss that warnings

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-groovy

I want to setup groovy to dismiss all warnings. I found the [posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59645378/jenkins-groovy-setup-for-security-warnings) to setup jenkins groovy for security warnings. But I did not find three ids of that warnings:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZwxuD.png)

Have I to take another ways to dismiss that warnings?

Comment: Looks like your image is not working. It should be mentioned that it's always better to paste text rather than a picture.

Comment: Can you convert your image to text so it can be easily understood?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those warnings are Administrative Monitor warnings.

**Jenkins > Manage Jenkins > Configure System > Administrative monitors configuration**. Click on the **Administrative monitors** button. [(Example)](https://docs.cloudbees.com/docs/cloudbees-ci/latest/cloud-secure-guide/beekeeper-security-warnings#_disable_the_security_warnings_administrative_monitor)

Disable any warnings with caution.

If using JCasC, you can add [steps to disable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53756840/how-to-disable-updates-in-jenkins/53758274).

You can achieve the same using [groovy](https://javadoc.jenkins.io/hudson/model/AdministrativeMonitor.html#disable-boolean-) and [groovy.init](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/managing/groovy-hook-scripts/).